# Insert page header/footer into chapter page in Latex

Tags: latex, header

I change the chapter style as following. I set up the header and footer by using fancyhdr package before the following code. But the problem is that only the chapter page doesn't include page header and footer, the rest of pages are fine. Could anyone tell me how to insert the header and footer into the chapter page? Thanks very much.

```
\makeatletter 
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 2pt \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{% \vspace*{10\p@}% 
{\parindent \z@    
  {\raggedleft \reset@font%
   \fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{b}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{22pt}{12}\selectfont%    
   \bfseries\thechapter\nobreak\hspace{1ex}}%   
  {\raggedright \reset@font%
   \fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{b}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{22pt}{12}\selectfont%
   \bfseries #1}%
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \par\nobreak
  \textcolor{orange}{\thickhrulefill}
  \vspace{26pt}
  \par\nobreak
}}
```

Comment: Move to [http://tex.stackexchange.com/](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't gotten an answer elsewhere already, you probably need to use `\thispagestyle{fancy}`, since most cover pages set pagestyle to empty.

Answer (score 5):

Chapter starting pages use the plain page style, so you could redefine that.

- With `fancyhdr` for example

  ```
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{...}
  ```
- With scrpage2 redefine `scrplain` or

  ```
  \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}
  ```
- Or simply make it equivalent

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
  \makeatother
  ```

  or `\ps@headings` etc.

Comment: Thanks for adding the KOMA-Script version. Worked perfectly.